# Got a fatal error saying "JVP does not exist. Differential-first differentiation APIs are experimental and should not be used."

Tags: swift, xcode, tensorflow, swift-for-tensorflow

I installed the TensorFlow toolchain in Xcode and tried running an example snippet from the S4TF GitHub page. I got the following error:

```
JVP does not exist. Differential-first differentiation APIs are experimental and should not be used.
```

I then tried doing the same on Google Colab and got the same error. Here's the snippet of code I'm trying to run:

```
@differentiable
func f(_ x: Float) -> Float {
    x * x
}
let dfdx = derivative(of: f)
dfdx(3) // 6
```

I understand that this is my first time running S4TF and I'm not aware of many things, so it might turn out to be a stupid mistake on my part :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing that error because you're attempting to take a forward-mode derivative, and support for that hasn't yet been implemented in the Swift automatic differentiation system. The current implementation supports reverse-mode differentiation, so you can use the `gradient` operator instead to obtain the result you want:

```
@differentiable
func f(_ x: Float) -> Float {
    x * x
}
let dfdx = gradient(of: f)
dfdx(3) // 6
```

Forward-mode differentiation support is in the works, but the focus is presently on upstreaming the reverse-mode implementation and refining that first. As a disclaimer, I work on the Swift for TensorFlow team.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  although I’m wondering why this example was given here when it’s not supported?

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/DifferentiableProgramming.md

Comment: @AdnanZahid - The Differentiable Programming Manifesto describes the design of the system as we'd like to see it in its final state. Many of the elements there have been implemented, but not all (thus the "partially implemented" status on the document). For example, the `@memberwise` attribute also hasn't been activated yet. There are also design issues that are undergoing active discussion with the community, so elements  of that may also change in response to that feedback.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification :)